# How to handle form at src attribute inside fancybox frame with Selenium Webdriver Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, popup, fancybox

I'm trying to sendKeys in the textfield inside form. But this form is put in the link. Attribute src refers to that link.

Here's the code

[image]

How could I reach textfield inside the link, because this link is in iframe and fancybox.

Comment: try List<WebElement> iframe = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(iframeCSSselector));
  System.out.println(iframe.size());
  driver.switchTo().frame(iframe.get(0));

Comment: I wrote those code

 List <WebElement> iframe;
    iframe = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".fancybox-iframe"));
    System.out.println(iframe.size()); 
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe.get(0));

And then there is error message that ask me to surround these code, because type list does not take parameters.

Comment: please past the full error log

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - type java.awt.List does not take parameters
 at recipes.UploadProdukPopup.main(UploadProdukPopup.java:114)
C:\Users\Indotrading\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 50 seconds)

Comment: can you past the html line of the frame

Comment: <div style="padding: 15px; width: auto; height: auto;" class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div style="overflow: auto; width: 600px; height: 343px;" class="fancybox-inner"><iframe src="addproductgroup.aspx?q=hS9DFK23Nh8Xk29sPZN9j%2bqXSaPgqztzgPT5ciA%2bzsyi8dL%2fnpNmqQ%3d%3d" scrolling="auto" id="fancybox-frame1468397970939" name="fancybox-frame1468397970939" class="fancybox-iframe" vspace="0" hspace="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe></div></div><a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;">

Comment: I see your frame id is "fancybox-frame1468397970939" hence try driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("fancybox-frame1468397970939")));

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the focus of the driver to the iFrame. You can use the below to switch to the iFrame

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("ID of your iFrame")));
```

Once it has switched focus you can perform the actions you need to within the form, and when you are done with the form you have to switch back out of the iframe and back onto the page using the below -

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: I already switch but it still not work because form is in src link.Set<String> s1=driver.getWindowHandles();Iterator<String> i1=s1.iterator();while(i1.hasNext()){String ChildWindow=i1.next();if(!s1.equals(ChildWindow))   {driver.switchTo().frame((WebElement) By.id("fancybox-frame1468307248480"));WebElement namaGroup = driver.findElement(By.id("txtProdukGroup"));namaGroup.sendKeys("Bunga Mawar");WebElement namaGroupEng = driver.findElement(By.id("txtProductGroupEnglish"));namaGroupEng.sendKeys("Rose Flower");WebElement btnSave =driver.findElement(By.id("btnAdd"));